# underscore js - list of items that occur above a certain number of times

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, underscore.js

I am trying to get a list of items that occur above a certain number of times. The following code extracts the ids from an array of objects. Then filters out those items that occur two or more times.

`item[1]` is the number of occurrences and `item[0]` is the Student id.

```
var list = _.chain(allpeople)
    .countBy(function(regentry) {
        return regentry.get("Student").id;
    })
    .pairs()
    .filter(function(item){
        if(item[1]>=2)
           return item[0];
    })
    .value();
```

I have two issues with this:

1. `list` is a 2D array (of id and occurrences -- see below) rather than just a list of ids. How do I make it just a list of ids?

   `0: "aaYiWFxdtV"
    1: 2`
2. This does not seem very efficient (when I have hundreds of items, I think this might not be the best way of doing it). Can I do this in less steps?

Comment: For (2), is your list sorted? If you are doing this multiple times, then it might be worth sorting your list first, then using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org)'s [_.findIndex](http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex) function but with the `isSorted` (`context`) parameter set to true. Once you get the index, you can use `slice` to get your full array. But, worth checking to see if this is worth the time saved though before you decide to go with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code can be simplified a bit and made to return what you want:

```
var result = _.chain(allpeople)
    .countBy(function(regentry) {
        return regentry.get('Student').id;
    })
    .pick(function(count){
        return count >= 2;
    })
    .keys()
    .value();
```

The [**countBy**](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy) function will return an object where the keys are the ids and their values will be their count. [**Pick**](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) can then be used to select the keys that pass the predicate (where the count is greater than or equal to 2).

```js
 var allpeople = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 }
 ];

 var result = _.chain(allpeople)
     .countBy(function(regentry) {
         return regentry.id;
     })
     .pick(function(count){
      return count >= 2;
     })
     .keys()
     .value();


    document.getElementById('results').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore.js"></script>

<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Comment: I tried this and countBy does return an object as you mentioned. But filter returns the count only (drops the ids as keys) and, therefore, keys returns '0', '1', '2', etc rather than the ids.

Comment: Oops - of course. Changed the code to use pick instead of filter and added a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) function just filters the array, but does not change the items. Therefore you should just return true|false in your predicate function here.

After filtering you can use [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) to change the resulting items.

```js
var list = _.chain(allpeople)
    .countBy(function (regentry) {
        return regentry.get('Student').id;
    })
    .pairs()
    .filter(function (item) {
        return item[1] >= 2;
    })
    .map(function (item) {
        return item[0];
    })
    .value();
```

Regarding your second question: I don't know of any other method to do this. But I'm not that familiar with underscore.js, either. Maybe someone else can answer here.